# Deploying New Versions Of JS + CSS seem to use cached version?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, webpack, browser-cache

I have a reactjs website that I am using with webpack and every time I deploy a new version of javascript or css it seems to always use the cached version.

I have to ctrl + F5 to see the changes (I have a very weird problem on one my test machines, that when I do that I see my changes, if I close the browser down and come back it shows me the old changes).

In my webpack I have done this

```
  new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].[hash].css",
      chunkFilename: "[id].[hash].css"
    }),

  output: {
    // filename and path are required
    filename: '[name].[hash].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    publicPath: '/'
  },
```

the first one is for the css and the second one is for my javascript. I am adding a hash which I thought would show the browser a new version is being used and to use it instead.

Comment: Your configuration seems to be correct. I think your browser cache is fooling you. Open the dev tool with F12, go to network tab there you will find a button or checkbox to clear your cache.

Comment: Maybe, but I am trying to mimic a user who would not know how to use F12. I guess I will have to do some more testing maybe it is just me.

Comment: @kmgt - how long will it be cached for? I just deployed a new verison onto production and I had to hit F5 for it to show the new version and that was from starting up chrome and going to the website. I need it that once they in this scenario they will see the latest code changes.